# CSS input text decoration

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve something like the website here: http://bit.ly/1f55jUR (where it says Space Min.) but I fail miserably lol..

Here is what I have done until now:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" id="box" /><span class="textbox2">TB</span>

.textbox {
   border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
   outline:0; 
   height:22px; 
   width: 30px; 
}
.textbox2 {
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
   padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
}
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/55Nb3/

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/55Nb3/2/

Comment: they are sing bootstrap class, you can get the css here => http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your html like this (span don't have the same properties than div):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" /><label for="textbox" clhttp://jsfiddle.net/55Nb3/#forkass="textbox2">TB</label>
```

**Here is the CSS**

```
   #textbox {
   border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
   outline:0; 
   height:30px; 
   width: 30px; 
   border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 16px;
}
label {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   border-left: none;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
   line-height: 30px;
   padding: 0 6px;
   height: 30px;
   border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Here is a link to it](http://jsfiddle.net/55Nb3/5/)

Answer (score 1):

They used Twitter Bootstrap on that website to get that styling: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by using a mix of jQuery and CSS

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], .post textarea').on('focus blur',function(e){
        if(e.type == 'focus' || e.type == 'focusout'){
            $(this).addClass('focussed');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('focussed');
        }
});
```

**CSS**

```
input{
  /* General style here */ 
}
input.focussed{
  /*Different styles for focussed input here */
}
```

Comment: CSS alone would be enough `input:focus{background:red;}`

Comment: @Slavenko Miljic - True however if the OP needs IE7 support this will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply mate! I was trying to avoid jQuery

Comment: Well if older browsers are not a concern, use the pseudo-class **:focus** as @SlavenkoMiljic said above. It's only a tiny snippet however if you want a pure JavaScript solution, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done an update on your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55Nb3/5

It's mostly done by:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And a few style adjustments.

It really doesn't matter if it is a `label` or something else.